# Approximating Average of Squares - Square of Average using Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: calculus, approximation, average

First, the simple problem: I have a set of points $\{(x_i, y_i)\}$ and want to approximate the average y-value, $<y> = \frac{1}{x_n - x_1} \int{y dx}$. Here I decided to use the trapezoidal rule to get a numerical approximation for the integral.

Okay, so now the slightly harder problem: I have the same set of points, but I want to calculate $<y^2> - <y>^2$. I already have $<y>$ so $<y>^2$ is no problem. I want to calculate $<y^2> = \frac{1}{x_n-x_1} \int{y^2 dx}$.

If we imagine the curve $y$ to be made of trapezoids, then the curve $y^2$ will be made of connected parabola segments.

**My first question:** would it make sense to approximate $<y^2>$ by calculating the area under these segments?

I worked out the math as follows. (Please double check to make sure I didn't make any mistakes):

Imagine a line segment between two adjacent points in the set: $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$.

We get the equation $y = m(x - x_1) + y_1$, where $m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}{y^2 \cdot dx} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}{(m(x - x_1) + y_1) \cdot dx}$$
$$ = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}{(m x - m x_1 + y_1) \cdot dx} $$
$$ = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}{m x \cdot dx} + \int_{x_1}^{x_2}{(-m x_1 + y_1) \cdot dx} $$
$$ = m \frac{x_2^2 - x_1^2}{2} + (-m x_1 + y_1) (x_2 - x_1) $$
$$ = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \frac{(\Delta x)(x_1+x_2)}{2} + y_1 \Delta x - \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} x_1 \Delta x $$
$$ = \frac{\Delta y (x_1+x_2)}{2} - x_1 \Delta y + y_1 \Delta x $$
$$ = (\frac{(x_1+x_2)}{2} - x_1) \Delta y + y_1 \Delta x $$
$$ = \frac{\Delta x}{2} \Delta y + y_1 \Delta x $$
$$ = (\frac{\Delta y}{2} + y_1) \Delta x $$
$$ \therefore <y^2> = \frac{1}{x_n - x_1} \sum_{1}^{n-1}{(\frac{\Delta y_i}{2} + y_i) \Delta x_i} $$

**My second question:** Does this make sense?

Comment: I realize I forgot to add the "squared" on the linear equation. I reworked the math and got $((\frac{\Delta x}{3} + y_1)\Delta y + y_1^2)\Delta x$

Comment: $((\frac{\Delta x \Delta y}{3} + y_1)\Delta y + y_1^2)\Delta x$